# Connecting Power Banks for USB dvices series

Tags: series

While I was trying to work out to rebuild the battery for my electric bike by replacing all 18650 cells, I saw a TV ad of the product called "MiniMax" which is a power bank for USB charging devices as well as jump start the cars with flat batteries (12V-13V).

Can I connect those "MiniMax" power bank thing series so that I can achieve 36V for my electric bike?
They are easy to charge and much cheaper than buying 60 of 18650.
Or I am totally wrong...

Thank you for your advice in advance.

Comment: easy to charge, but do they charge quickly enough?

Answer (score 2):

If the ad suggests it can start a car, I call b#llsh#t ! That device will not be capable to jump start a car in the same way as the you can use another car or a proper jump starter like this:

[image: proper jump starter]

**Notice that:**

This one is **much** larger because it contains a lead-acid battery

Notice how it uses big-#ss cables for huge currents

When charged this thing can start a car with a fully depleted battery immediately or at least within minutes.

That MiniMax is a completely different product, it's a powerbank with a 12V output option. Maybe if a car battery misses just that little bit of power it needs to start the car, a MiniMax might crank up the voltage just a bit (you might have to wait half an hour for the car battery to be charged by the MiniMax) so that you can start your car.

But looking at the shape, the MiniMax will contain a few 18650 cells. But these will **by far** not contain the same amount of energy as the device in the picture.

And regarding buying 18605 cells or devices containing these: you get what you pay for. If you buy cheap ones **I guarantee you** that these will be a dissapointment. **Good** 18650 cells are made by Sony, LG, Sanyo, Samsung for example. Their capacity will be 3500 mAh maximum each. Cells with a higher capacity are "stretching the truth". These cells from reliable manufacturers cost about 4 to 5 US dollar each. At a lower price I would not trust them to be any good and not worth buying.